# Jest and Commitizen: Commit works even if tests fail

Tags: babel-jest, vuepress, husky, commitizen

I am currently using Jest, Husky, Commitizen, and Vuepress. However, when jest tests or the build fails, the commit hook still works. How can I fix this to exit the commitizen hook when things fail? Here is the relevant lines in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vuepress build docs
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue docs/.vuepress",
    "test": "npm run lint && jest --coverage --coverageDirectory='__coverage__'",
    "test:full": "npm run test && npm run build",
    "commit": "cz",
    ...
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "prepare-commit-msg": "npm run test:full && exec < /dev/tty && git cz --hook || true"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "commitizen": "^4.2.3",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    ...
  },
  "config": {
    "commitizen": {
      "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - it was simple. I needed to add the following to husky:

```
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run test:full",
      ...
    }
  },
```